# Celery: Running tasks when they are modular

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I am using celery to run scheduled tasks in django. My tasks are in `tasks.py` .
The thing if I break my function to smaller ones like this :

```
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab()) 
def run_something():
    print 'a'
    run_something_else('a')

def run_something_else(a)
   print a
```

Now `celery.log` says only `run_something` task was executed. It somehow doesn't execute `run_something_else()`
Can someone explain this behaviour ?

Comment: `run_something_else` is not a task, it's just a function, Celery hasn't brokered its execution and wouldn't know about it.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco Oh, ok! But then how would I make my tasks modular ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? It's unclear what your objective is here.

Comment: This is just a snippet to explain. I have tasks which are big and are written into multiple functions. One function passes arguments to other and so on.

Comment: The code in `run_something_else` here will still run. It will not be reported as a `Task` since Celery doesn't know about its execution. It's OK to do that to break down one task in multiple functions if needed. If you *want* steps of your task execution to go through the broker again, then make a new Task and `.delay()` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain your tasks as mentioned [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chains). But this is available form version `3.0.` Not sure if you are looking for this.